# CSS 3D Cube Z-Index Issue When Rotating

Tags: css

I've created a basic 3D cube using CSS and `<div>`s. However, when it animates, the sides are not "overlapping" properly. It's a bit hard to explain, so see the http://jsfiddle.net/JNCNr/ to see precisely what I mean. I've read through some SO posts, the MDN, and so forth, but I am not quite sure what is causing my issue. I simply want the sides to behave properly when they rotate behind each other.

EDIT: Right now it's working for Chrome only.

Here is some of my CSS:

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;

    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

    /* for 3d animations */
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
}

.box {
    /* size */
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor: move;
    /* color */
    opacity: 1;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#666, #333);
    border: 1px solid black;
    /* 3d stuff */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50px 50px -50px;
}

.s1 {
    -webkit-animation: as1 4s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes as1 {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, -270deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg);
    }
}
```

Thanks~!

Comment: All I see is a square. I guess your thing works in Google Chrome only.

Comment: I can see the cube, you mean you want the sides facing to obscure the sides that have just rotated?

Comment: I'm in Chrome 27, I can see the square, but I don't see any animation.

Comment: @adaam Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `backface-visibility: hidden` to hide the parts of element that have been rotated to show the backface:

```css
.s1, .s2, .s3, .s4 {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/JNCNr/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It solves my problem when the opacity of each side of the cube is 1. However, this does not solve my problem when each side has an opacity < 1. Is the only solution to this to create 8 sides, where each "real" side has 2 of these fake sides assigned to it, one when it is in front of the cube and one when it is behind? Or is there a better way? Once again, thanks.

Comment: @lucasjcm: There is actually a better way! (Well, I like the hypercube effect, but if you insist on fixing it...) You can make all of the sides fixed in their proper positions, then just animate the container, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/JNCNr/2/

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thanks.